# Using PhysX, how can I predict where I will need to generate procedural terrain collision shapes?

Tags: collision-detection, procedural-generation, terrain, physx

In this situation, I have terrain height values I generate procedurally. For rendering, I use the camera's position to generate an appropriate sized height map. For collision, however, I need to have height fields generated in areas where objects may intersect.

My current potential solution, which may be naive, is to iterate over all "awake" physics actors, use their bounds/extents and velocities to generate spheres in which they may reside after a physics update, then generate height values for ranges encompassing clustered groups of actors. Much of that data is likely already calculated by PhysX already, however.

Is there some API, maybe a set of queries, even callbacks from the spatial system, that I could use to predict where terrain height values will be needed?

Comment: Seems to me like you already coded the best solution. Not sure how PhysX works, maybe you can instead have bounding box shaped triggers on your terrain chunks and generate the collision shapes if something enters (triggers) this box. Basically what you are doing but the other way around and with PhysX collision math.

Answer (score -1):

If you are generating meshes from your data for rendering you could pass the mesh off to PhysX as a collider Mesh. Meaning that physX and your renderer reference the same object cutting overhead.

Comment: It's not appropriate to assume that *visible* terrain is the *only* terrain objects can collide with. The issue is quickly identifying what range of terrain could be collided with so that collision shapes can be generated for them on-demand.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octree
dividing the world data up into cubes and "slicing" them up where ever you have a free collidable entity you can then make calls to the terrain data within a very small area with very little overhead. 
Here is an example using quadtrees for 2D particle collision but the concept is the same for Octrees but with an extra dimension.
This would also allow for individual free collidable objects to collide with each other.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fuexOsLOfl0
You can then generate very small colliders from the terrain data near the free collidable objects

Comment: I'm familiar with octrees and spatial partitioning - PhysX is already doing that internally. I need information from PhysX regarding its spatial partitioning system so that I can generate terrain collision shapes where they are necessary because the terrain is procedural.

Comment: I don't get why you're not just making calls to the data for the terrain and sampling that data to build the mesh.
I would imagine that physX would use something like this.collider.position or something like that when referencing an existing object or collider

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/physx/Docs/Shapes.html
might help

Comment: You're missing the point. I am generating data for the terrain. I am sampling that data to build a heightfield. I need to predict where terrain data is needed. If there's an object at (-100.0, -100.0), I need to generate terrain near (-100.0, -100.0) before I simulate physics. I also need to generate a region of terrain big enough or else an object may move beyond a region and end up below where the terrain would be if it had been generated in that region. PhysX must already track such information in order to predict potential collisions - I need that information. I don't know if/how to do so.

Comment: Here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13804606/find-the-position-of-an-object-in-physx-at-run-time
Sorry for misunderstanding the question first time round
You could check the position of the object and then the bounds then generate any terrain that is intersected by the bounds plus a tolerance factor of 5 units or something.

Comment: You can get the velocity of an object and direction and shift your bounds in that direction by calculating the predicted position in x amount of Physics Frames.
Essentially looking ahead of the physics. I had to do something similar to this before when over coming Physics tunneling with fast moving projectiles. only instead of looking for potentially collidable objects you want to create them before the object hits it

Comment: That's the work around method I outlined in my question, yes. I'm asking if I can get the work that PhysX has already done, so that I'm not redundantly calculating the same results. I haven't found a way yet, but I'm not that familiar with the PhysX API without licensing.

Comment: I think PhysX calculates on a per step basis meaning it won't know where its going to be beyond the next step.
It sounds like you need to know a few steps ahead of the physics step to give you time to calculate and generate.
The solution of looking ahead by checking velocity and direction to see where it will be is best

Comment: What number of actors do you have and how large is your terrain? How often will actors be close enough to one another to need to share the same terrain sampling? How do you deal with line-of-sight queries over large ranges?